# Are the "Highlighted" destructible items in Diablo 3 significant in any way?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed that I come across destructibles (doors, barrels, other props) that have a kind of highlight, a double helix type of spiral with some effect.

Do these items have any significance?

Here's an animated GIF that shows such an object. Pay attention to the left hand side where a large multi-story wooden scaffolding has such a highlight. I looped the video back and forth to make it easier to see.

[image: x]

I am kinda hoping for some kind of Easter Egg or something, but does anyone know what it means?

I'm playing Xbox One if that is significant.

Something I just thought of, this effect seems very similar to the one given out by the Haunt skill I'm using, since I'm playing a witch doctor. This effect spreads to nearby enemies, could it be that it just spreads to inanimate objects and thus only provide a visual effect?

Comment: I wonder if that's console-only? I've never seen that effect in the PC version... but I also haven't really played the WD much either

Comment: Items do have a minimal amount of health, and are triggered by destroying them, so i think you are correct that your haunt is applied to the scaffolding. Full disclosure, i have 2 lvl 70 witch doctors, including my current seasonal character, and I've never noticed this happen with haunt. I'll keep an eye out though.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt I clearly meant to write "descructible" :)

Comment: I know, right! I also enjoy making up words. Maybe I should have left it... this was a good one.

Comment: The made up words are the best ones. I have the best made up words. Nobody makes better words than me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is the Haunt skill. When you use and there is no enemy on the Haunt's range, the Haunt will effect destructible items.
You can make a test on a place with some destructible items and no enemy, like Act 5 or dungeon on Act 2. Just spam Haunt while you run and you see the Haunt will apply on the items and destroy them.

This thing its good on PC because, when you break some destructible items you gain a speed boost for a short time. So, keep breaking those items to get extra speed.

My founts: I have like 200 hours with WD and one entire season with the Haunt set.

Comment: I confirm this. I'm playing WD on PS4 too. This **is** the Haunt skill.

Comment: By the way the *destruction boost* was first implemented on consoles in the vanilla diablo 3 and 1-2 years later it was ported to PC.

Comment: @OttoV. I have no idea, I just don't play on console, only PC, I will edit right now.

Comment: I was not offending you. Just some trivia info. ;)

Comment: Don't worry men, I just prefer to give clear and correct information, so thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Some destructible items may cause an effect in the game, in this case the scaffolding will probably trigger some rocks to fall on enemies and temporarily stun them and deal some damage.

Others that do not have effects (tables, doors, etc) will not be highlighted.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is correct as I've seen the same highlight on barrels, the non-exploding kind, which seems to just implode if I attack them and drop money at the most.

Comment: Could the fact that I'm playing a witch doctor have anything to do with it? The effect seems similar to the Haunt spell I'm using, could this spell also attach itself to a non-mob item and simply do nothing other than provide a visual effect?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ah yes.  Haunt does attach itself to destructables as well